# Removing Empty Line in a file without Removing Indentation Python

Tags: python

Well I have a python code named "remove_empty_line.py" that delete Empty line from a file "a.py", the problem is that code, delete all Indentation which affect "a.py" execution. So my question is how to solve this problem, I mean deleting Empty lines with Indentation conserving.

Here is the code "remove_empty_line.py" :

```
import fileinput 
for lines in fileinput.FileInput("a.py", inplace = True) :
    lines = lines.strip()
    if lines = '': continue
    print lines
```

for example "a.py" is something like that :

```
if 1==1 :

    print "hello world"

else :

    print "this is a test file"
```

Applying "remove_empty_line.py" on "a.py" give me the below result :

```
if 1==1 :
print "hello world"
else :
print "this is a test file"
```

And I want the Output file "a.py" to be like below :

```
if 1==1 :
    print "hello world"
else :
    print "this is a test file"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
open('a_mod.py','w').write(''.join(l for l in open("a.py") if l.rstrip()))
```

Comment: Hi @Tanmaya Meher, I tried the above command, but I received an Error Msg saying : syntax error near unexpected token 'a_mod.py','w'

Comment: @SalahElaroussi Probably you forgot a `parenthesis` / have extra `parenthesis`. The code is OK.I double checked it. Just check your code. Its a `syntax error` not `logical error`.

Answer (score 2):

do not overwrite the `lines` variable with the stripped version. You should also name your variable `line` for improved readability since it is only one line at a time. Instead of doing a continue if the variable is empty, do something only when the variable contains something.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput('a.py', inplace = True) :
    if line.strip():    # check if the stripped version contains something
        print line
```

Comment: @ enrico.bacis OK, let's say tht your code above gives me a 50% help. thx a lot ;) but still get empty lines, ok I will take care about the rest